# jqquery-ias in joomla doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, css, joomla, pagination

I've an article in joomla 3 with php code like this:

```
<?php
include(config.php);
$limit = 10; #item per page
# db connect
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die('Could not connect to MySQL DB ') .         mysql_error();
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link); 

$page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
# sql query
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM actor_info ORDER BY id DESC";
# find out query stat point
$start = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
# query for page navigation
if( mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > ($page * $limit) ){
$next = ++$page;
}
 $query = mysql_query( $sql . " LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
echo 'Page not found!';
exit();
}
?>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/test/js/js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
// Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
jQuery.ias({
container : '#content', // main container where data goes to append
item: ".post",
pagination: "#content .navigation a",
next: ".next-posts a",
loader: '<img src="css/ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
triggerPageThreshold: 3 // show load more if scroll more than this
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<h1><a href="#">Data load while scroll</a></h1>

 <!-- loop row data -->
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): ?>
<div class="item" id="item-<?php echo $row['id']?>">
<h2>
<span class="num"><?php echo $row['id']?></span>
<span class="name"><?php echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name']?></span>
</h2>
<p><?php echo $row['film_info']?></p>
</div>
<?php endwhile?>

<!--page navigation-->
<?php if (isset($next)): ?>
<div class="nav">
 <div class="next-posts"><a href='test?p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a></div>
 </div>
<?php endif?>
 </div><!--.wrap-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Now it wokrs for retrive data from DB but when I'd like to obrtain the scroll effect it stops...so it appears a link "NEXT" that bring me to the next page /test?p=2 and more

How can I solve it?

I put this code in an article through a plugin called SOURCERER

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.

It's bad practice mixing code and content. But mixing old school php in your articles is simply nuts.

You're trying to go against the framework and not with it. You're making your life miserable, your code ugly and unmaintainable, your site vulnerable. Everyday you stick to this approach a kitten dies.

So you want infinite scrolling? Very nice.  Your code could work, I'm not familiar with IAS, but you need to move it elsewhere (and you need to migrate the `mysql_connect` statements - you want to use JDatabase) and change the initialization from:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

Where should your code go?  Provided it needs to be re-invoked for each page which you want to infinitely scroll to, you have several options:

- a template override
- a content plugin
- a module
- a dedicated controller you can invoke
- a combination of the above (i.e. template override or module for the initial call, controller for the next page results)

possibly a module might be the easiest place.  Your module will be placed in a position just below the content of the article, and after the initial load, determine by the parameters if the request is that of a second page, and return only its markup (by killing the joomla processing as soon as it hits the module)